# Compare javascript arrays of objects and set specific values which applies to both additions and deletions from main array source

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

Given the following array setup:

```
let myArray1 = [
    {"name": "F1"},
    {"name": "F2"},
    {"name": "F3"},
    {"name": "F4"},
    {"name": "F5"},
];

let myArray2 = [
    {
      "groupName": "Group 1",
      "groupDetails": [ 
            {
              "name": "F1",
              "value1": 10,
              "value2": 22
            },
            {
              "name": "F2",
              "value1": 14,
              "value2": 25
            },
            {
              "name": "F3",
              "value1": 9,
              "value2": 2
            }
       ]
    },
    {
      "groupName": "Group 2",
      "groupDetails": [ 
            {
              "name": "F1",
              "value1": 110,
              "value2": 222
            },
            {
              "name": "F2",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 55
            },
            {
              "name": "F3",
              "value1": 12,
              "value2": 12
            }
       ]
    }
]
```

I need to determine the difference between the contents of `myArray1` and `myArray2` and ensure that for each `groupDetails` array within `myArray2` reflects the same name value always of `myArray1`.

Where the name entries in `myArray1` do not exist in `myArray2`, I need to push to the `groupDetails` array, the following, using `myArray1` contents and defaulting the other values to 0, i.e.:

```
            {
              "name": "F4",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "F5",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 0
            }
```

So end result required for `myArray2` and specifically `groupDetails` array, would now look like this:

```
let myArray2 = [
    {
      "groupName": "Group 1",
      "groupDetails": [ 
            {
              "name": "F1",
              "value1": 10,
              "value2": 22
            },
            {
              "name": "F2",
              "value1": 14,
              "value2": 25
            },
            {
              "name": "F3",
              "value1": 9,
              "value2": 2
            },
            {
              "name": "F4",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "F5",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 0
            }
       ]
    },
    {
      "groupName": "Group 2",
      "groupDetails": [ 
            {
              "name": "F1",
              "value1": 110,
              "value2": 222
            },
            {
              "name": "F2",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 55
            },
            {
              "name": "F3",
              "value1": 12,
              "value2": 12
            },
            {
              "name": "F4",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "F5",
              "value1": 0,
              "value2": 0
            }

       ]
    }
]
```

This is for both additions and removals from `myArray1`

With all the manipulation required, I'm unsure how to compare the difference and set the specific values above as well as remove the name entries that were originally in `myArray1` from `myArray2`.

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
myArray2.map((data) => {
  myArray1.map((data1) => {
    let indexData = data.groupDetails.findIndex(
      (groupData) => groupData.name === data1.name
    );
    if (indexData === -1) {
      data.groupDetails = [
        ...data.groupDetails,
        { name: data1.name, value1: 0, value2: 0 },
      ];
    }
  });
});
console.log(myArray2);
```